# Two friends are playing a board game that requires each of them to roll a die. Each player uses her/his own die.

Tags: probability, dice

I'm just doing some practice problems to identify sample spaces. I Need help knowing if my logic is right

a) What is the sample space for a single roll if their dice are painted two different colors?

My best guess was that the Sample space is $S=\{\{x_j|1\le j\le6\} \cup\{x_k|1\le k\le6\}\}$ where the $\{x_j|1\le j\le6\}$ is the case where the first friend rolls with his unique die first and the $\{x_k|1\le k\le6\}$ is the case where the second friend rolls with his unique die first.

b) What's the sample space for a single roll if their dice are the same color? Does this change anything?

I believe that since they're the same color it's just

$S=\{x_j|1\le k \le 6\}$ since they're the same color they're no second color/case to consider, so that's the difference.

c) What if one friend rolls both dice (I assume that the dice are distinct, it doesn't specify). Does this change anything?

I think the answer is $S =\{(x_j,x_k)|1\le x_j,x_k \le6\}$ Since it's just one friend rolling both dice for them and since they're distinct dice, order matters thus we should consider all the different possible $(x_j,x_k)$ outcomes.

Do I have this right? Please let me know if I've misinterpreted anything. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your answer in part C is correct.  Unfortunately, it's also the answer for parts A and B.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I'm really so confused on why? Isn't part A and B, just rolling One Di, so shouldn't it be different from C? What am I misinterpreting here with my logic?

Comment: [Probability theory](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory) is [about the measure-theoretic foundations](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8587/290189) of stochastics.  The tag ([tag:probability-theory]) should be used for questions concerning this subject, not for questions about calculating a specific probability.  Use ([tag:probability]) instead, see also [meta](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1686/290189).

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that, will note in the future

Comment: Unless something weird is going on, if the dice are fair then all three parts have a probability of $\frac1{36}$ of two $6$s appearing, because they are essentially the same.  So that outcome should be part of the sample space

Comment: So I should consider both die for part a and b, not just one as ultimately "single roll" means both player 1 rolls and player 2 rolls their di so two dice are thrown in total not one, correct? Is that's what I'm misinterpreting?